# API methods make infinite loop, I don't understand

Tags: java, android, layout-inflater

```java
//LayoutInflater.java

public static LayoutInflater from(Context context) {//---(1)
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater =
            (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);//--(2)
    ...
    return layoutInflater;
}

//ContextThemeWrapper.java

@Override
public Object getSystemService(String name) {//--(2)
    if (LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE.equals(name)) {
        if (mInflater == null) {
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).cloneInContext(this);//--(1)
        }
        return mInflater;
    }
    return getBaseContext().getSystemService(name);
}
```

Note that two methods (1)from(Context) and (2)getSystemService(String) 
 calls each other infinitely I don't understand how it works..
 I don't think It's supposed to work like this.
 I'm stuck. Can you help me? am I missing something?

Comment: Not every `Context` is a `ContextThemeWrapper`.

Comment: An infinite loop should not occur. Notice how getSystemService() in the ContextWrapper class calls getBaseContext(). The base implementation should return your desired service or throw an exception(or just return null) if you've provided an incorrect name.

Comment: my another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42248449/methods-that-call-each-other-infinitely) makes it clear that my desired service is LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE and the Context you get from getBaseContext() is from the ContextWrapper's constructor. this constructor was given Activity instance by AppCompatDelegate.create(this, this) in the AppCompatActivity Class.. so I think this Context is ContextThemWrapper..